# Convert a Int16Array to a ndarray using ndarrays.js nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multidimensional-array, vtk

I have 245 Dicom images taken from [here](https://mri.radiology.uiowa.edu/VHDicom/VHMCT1mm/VHMCT1mm_Head.tar.gz), each of size 512x512. I was able to create a `Int16Array` out of them which is of size `512*512*245` using the [node-vtk](https://github.com/axkibe/node-vtk) module.

Now the problem is, how to covert this Typed Array to a proper volume using [ndarray.js](https://github.com/scijs/ndarray). I need  to do this so that I can select a slice in the series and do something with it.

I tried this :

```
// Get the dicom series output
var vtkVolume = reader.getOutput( );

// Get the pointData
var vtkVolumePointData = vtkVolume.getPointData( ); 

// Get arrayData as vtkDataArray{}
var vtkVolumeArray = vtkVolumePointData.getArray( 0 );

// SafeDownCast it
var tmp = ( new vtk[ vtkVolumeArray.getClassName( ) ] ).safeDownCast( vtkVolumeArray ); // Safe cast it down

// Custom function that was provided which will give you the 512*512*245 Int16Array
var volume_buffer = tmp.getBuffer( );

var volume = ndarray(volume_buffer,[512,512,245]);
var slice = volume.pick(null,null,115); 

// Display the slice using an external library like plotly.js
```

When I try this, the images dont show up properly(comes as pixelated line with a black background).

I also tried another approach where I use a library known as [daikon.js](https://github.com/rii-mango/Daikon) which allows me to load the images, get the specific arrays of each image and display it. But when I try to create the `volume` out of all them,it just doesnt work.

Is there a way to work around this problem and load the images properly into the ndarray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to fix it, the problem was the shape of array when stored. I had to change the order of it to this :

```
var volume = ndarray(volume_buffer,[245,512,512]);
var slice = volume.pick(115,null,null);
```

This gave the correct image and it was displayed properly.